# Can $1-e^{-\phi M}$ approximate to $M$ as $\phi$ approaches zero?

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems

I am running numerical simulations of a 2 dimensional ODE system such that:

$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}= (1-e^{-M\phi})\alpha U M  - \beta D  M\\
\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}=\beta D M - \gamma D
$$
where the variables $\{M,U,D\}\in[0,1]$ and $M+U+D=1$

All parameters ($\alpha,\phi,\beta,\gamma$) are independent of $t$.

When $\phi$ approaches zero, the above system behaves exactly as the system below:
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}= \alpha U M^2  - \beta D  M\\
\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}=\beta D M - \gamma D
$$

My college maths date far back, but if I am not missing anything $\lim_{\phi\to0} 1-e^{-M\phi}=0$. Then could the behaviour of the system when $\phi$ approaches zero be related to the bounded nature of M,U, and D?

Although this result matches my expectations, I am clueless as to how this occurs...

Thanks in advance if anyone has a clue.

Comment: Does $\phi$ depend on $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding out as a Taylor series, $$e^{-M \phi} = 1 -M \phi + \frac {(M \phi)^2}{2!}-...  $$and so $$1-e^{M \phi} = M \phi - \frac {(M \phi)^2}{2!}+... $$ As $\phi$ approaches $0$, $1-e^{M \phi}$ approaches $M \phi$, as the higher order terms are negligibly small in comparison. This means that:
$\frac{1-e^{-M \phi}}{\phi} $ approximates $M$ as $\phi $ goes to $0$, so no, the statement in your title isn't generally true.

Comment: Your argument shows that as $\phi \to 0$, $\frac{1 - e^{M\phi}}{\phi}$ approaches $M$, which differs from what OP asks....

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I did not think of using taylor series. I guess I came up with a similar (although newbie) approach thinking that $e^{-M\phi}$ might approximate to the linear function $1-M\phi$ when $\phi$ is small... In that case and in the first order of the taylor series, could we say $M\phi$ approximates to $M$ for small $\phi$?

Comment: @0SoGood No; for example, $3\times 10^{-n}$ does not approximate $3$ as $n\to \infty$...

Comment: Actually, Andrew brings up a good point. I was a bit careless in my implementation. You are correct in assuming that $e^{-M \phi}$ approximates the linear function $1-M \phi$ as $\phi$ approaches $0$. This comes directly from the Taylor series. But really, it should be that $\frac{1-e^{-M \phi}}{\phi} $ approximates $M$ as $\phi $ goes to $0$. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. The use of the Taylor series easily solved my problem!